White board dry erase markers dry out
I have dry erase markers from Expo. When I don't use them for a while they dry out and cannot be used. Do you have any tips on how to get them usable again?

No but a tip to keep them longer, keep them laying flat on their side from new.

Whatever 'Expo' means, can you say whether they also dry out if you do use them? Doesn't that matter?
Either way, getting them usable again should depend on its base liquid, so can you say whether your markers are oil- or solvent- or water-based, or what else?

I recently "revived" one of those by holding the tip under warm water a few seconds.
